# Using angularjs ui-router $state.go() inside IFrame

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

I am using angularjs, angular-ui-router.js. Application launched inside IFrame on another site(host).

At start otherwise state runs, but after running `$state.go('home', {}, { location: false })` nothings happens . ui-view is still empty and pages/home.html isn't loaded.

Application works fine without IFrame and in Safari.
But doesn't work in Chrome.

```
<ui-view></ui-view> <!-- Look to pages/home.html-->


$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/otherwise');
$stateProvider.state("otherwise", {
    url: "/otherwise",
    template: "",
    data: {
        requireLogin: false
    },
    controller: ['$state',
        function ($state) {
            $state.go('home', {}, { location: false })
        }]
});

$stateProvider.state("home", {
    url: "/home",
    templateUrl: "pages/home.html",
    controller: "",
    params: {
        recalcStates: false
    },
    resolve: {
        dataForDay: function(DataService){
            return DataService.loadData();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: errors in console should give you clues as to what the issue is

Comment: There is no errors in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was when initialize DataService from home state resolve block, there was attempt to gain access to iframe parent window JS variable. It throw security exception, but angular-ui-router encapsulated it and console was empty.